# Double Label for Json Property C#

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net, double

I need to pass a Json object to an API, but the API requires the Json properties to have a double label of sorts, such as:

```
{
     "name:id":"1234"
}
```

However, using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq, I can't get this to format the label exactly. Here is what I've tried so far (which throws an error)

```
dynamic json= new JObject();
json.name.id = "1234";
```

Doing

```
json.id = "1234";
```

Works just fine. I have also tried

```
json.name = new JProperty("id", "1234");
```

Which also throws an error. I have also tried hard coding the json file as a single string and converting that to a JObject, which also threw an error. Is what I'm trying to do possible or am I missing something? Is there another Json package I could use that would support what I want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JObject's string [indexer notation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Item_1.htm).

```
dynamic json = new JObject();
json["name.id"] = "1234";
```

Since the json is essentially built as a key/value pair, using a string indexer can allow you to overcome atypical property names.

Answer (score 0):

There multiple ways to achieve that.

You can use `JsonProperty` attribute and specify the property name as `name:id` like:

```
class MyClass
{
    [JsonProperty("name:id")]
    public string Name_Id { get; set; }
}
```

and then you can do:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
obj.Name_Id = "1234";
var strJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

and you will get back:

```
{"name:id":"1234"}
```